# Ionic - Push Token disappearing

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

The scenario:

1. The user goes well on the SignUP Process (account created on apps.ionic.io) -> getting the User ID
2. Registering to the push service -> getting the Push Token and setting that into the ionicUser OK
3. Checking the token into apps.ionic.io -> the user has the token correctly
4. Sending a push using curl

   ```
   curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_KEY" 
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
        -d '{"tokens": ["USER_TOKEN"], "profile": "production_profile", "notification": { "message": "Hello World!" } }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
   ```

However, just after sending the push, the token disappears from the user, I can only recover it when I logged in again with the user on the mobile app.

I just sent the question to ionic support, if I have any news about it I will post the answer here

Comment: Any news? also having this problem...

Comment: not a solution, but at least a "forum" @SDude https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/when-i-send-a-push-the-users-token-disappears/56341/9